# How to implement a track for a wipeout-style game on a mobile device?

Tags: 3d, racing

I was wondering what is the best way to manage a 3D track for a game with the same mechanic as Wipeout on a mobile device. Build a track out of multiple segments and load new segments as the player advances or build just one single mesh, maybe with multiple level of details ?

I'm very unfamiliar with this kind of problems so suggestions for other approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 3D games, usually you implement two tracks : one with very basic level of detail (just a floor and 2 walls) that you use to compute the collisions and physics. 
Then you add another data, probably with different LODs for rendering, that you can load as the player advances.

Also if your game stays basic, meaning you keep the same width along the whole track, you can just store a 3D curve, and use it for the collisions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the 3D curve, wouldn't it be expensive (and complicated) to calculate the collisions with a curve ?

Comment: I don't think so, because a curve can be described with accurate precision with only a few control points. To achieve the same precision, using polygons, you'd need a lot of tesselation. As for being complicated, you'd need first to find the nearest point to your player on the curve, then detect if you're too far from the curve or not. Then of course you could add more precision and detail on the collision, but something as simple as that could work, especially on a phone.